# Python - Threads not parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have my runner code that starts 5 threads, however, it only starts 1 thread (by which I know because it doesn't loop), take a look at the code:

```
import Handle
import threading

h = Handle.Handle()
h.StartConnection()
for i in range(0, 5):
    print("Looped")
    t = threading.Thread(target=h.Spawn())
    t.start()
```

It only prints "Looped" once and only runs "Spawn" once aswell. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to know, that there is a huge difference between a true [PARALLEL] and just [CONCURRENT] code-execution models. Threads, not speaking about GIL-issues, do not provide a warranty of [PARALLEL] execution, but may help organise a [CONCURRENT] type of processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues I noticed:

- You are replacing the `t` variable in each loop. So finally you just have one thread assigned to it.
- Does the `Spawn` function return a function? If it does then it's okay, otherwise you should just pass `Spawn` to the target, not call `Spawn()` .
- If the `Spawn` function is long running in nature (I assume it is), then your call to the `Spawn` function will block the loop and wait until it returns. This is why your loop might print "looped" once and the Spawn function getting called just once too.

My suggestion would be like this:

```
import Handle
import threading

h = Handle.Handle()
h.StartConnection()

threads = []

for i in range(0, 5):
    print("Looped")
    t = threading.Thread(target=h.Spawn)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

I took a list to store the threads - the `threads` list. Then appending each of the thread in it before calling `start`. Now I can iterate over the `threads` list anytime I want (may be for `join`ing them?).

Also since I assumed `Spawn` is a long running function, I passed it as the target to the `Thread` constructor. So it should be run in background when we call `start` on the thread. Now it should no longer block the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are not running threads, you run the `Spawn`-method right in the main thread. target needs to be a function, not the result of that function:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=h.Spawn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .

```
import Handle
import threading

h = Handle.Handle()
h.StartConnection()
for i in range(0, 5):
    print("Looped")
    threading.Timer(5.0, h).start()
```

Comment: What does the Timer do? Where is the `Spawn` function?